# How to Guess the 6-D Location of an Object relative to a calibrated Camera

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, location, camera-calibration

I calibrated a mono Camera using MATLAB's Camera Calibrator App using a Checkerboard.
From this I got all Camera Parameters saved in `calibrationSession`.

With the same camera I took a picture of an Object (`sceneImage`). 
I also have a plain picture showing just the object without any rotation (`objImage`). 
And I know the real width and height of the object.

With the SURF Feature Detector I extracted the features thereof an matched them.

Now i want to guess/calculate the 6-D location of the object, which i know the features of, in the picture i took with the calibrated camera.

There is my MATLAB code so far:

```
% IMPORTS
model = imread('model.png');
scene = imread('scene.png');
load('calibrationSession');

% IMG PREP
cameraParams = calibrationSession.CameraParameters;
objImage = rgb2gray(model);
[sceneImage, newOrigin] = undistortImage(rgb2gray(scene),cameraParams);

I1 = sceneImage;
I2 = objImage;

% DETECTION
points1 = detectSURFFeatures(I1);
[features1, valid_points1] = extractFeatures(I1, points1);

points2 = detectSURFFeatures(I2);
[features2, valid_points2] = extractFeatures(I2, points2);

[indexPairs,matchmetric] = matchFeatures(features1,features2);

matchedPoints1 = valid_points1(indexPairs(:,1),:);
matchedPoints2 = valid_points2(indexPairs(:,2),:);

% LOCATION
objwidth = 126;
objheight = size(I2,2)*objwidth/size(I2,1);
```

Comment: Hey! Just wanted to know what you ended up doing about this problem?  Additionally, a friendly complain, after looking at your history: I think it would be cool if you could interact a bit with people that answer you. Otherwise... What's the point?

Comment: Hey thanks, sorry for not replying.
But i am still a bit confused with how stackoverflow does not allow beginners to interact properly, like i am not allowed to write comments unless they are below my own answers and stuff like that. Also i often get a -1 like here for asking a question and i am like why?

Long story short, i quit with this task here in matlab becuase the problem was that i could not get SURF to detect the 4 edges of the object in the scene and furthermore as it was part of my studies and it came out that a compile able solution was not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Edit: i double checked all my questions, and in nearly every case i interacted with the people who gave answers.

This topic i forgot because it lost its meaning to me when my studies finished in february, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't describe the type of camera/object motion precisely, so I will just assume that the camera moves enough for us to have a baseline (to estimate depth). Then, we'll first assume that the object is static. In that case, I'll suggest you first try more classical methods: start by computing the relative motion between the two instants you images were taken, *i.e* between the two cameras. If your features are correctly matched, this can be easily done via computing the Essential matrix (See [this matlab guide](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimateessentialmatrix.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop). I personally prefer the method of [this paper](http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/2013/Papers/paper0116/paper0116.pdf), but it takes time to implement). Once you have the Essential matrix, you can easily extract the relative motion in the form of a rotation and a translation (*i.e.* `[R|T]`) matrix. Now you can triangulate your feature points and get a sparse 3d map. However, your `T` will only be known up to scale, and therefore, so will be your estimation of the object's size and location.

That is where you'll want to start exploiting your knowledge of the object's width and height. If the object is simple (*i.e.* a cube), and the motions are not too violent (*e.g.* no upside down etc), then you can deduce the scale from that. For example, in the case of the cube, imagine that your first image is just a view of a face, i.e. the image looks something like

```
A ----- B
|       |
|       |
C-------D
```

Now that you have triangulated the feature points, you have four points `{P_A,P_B,P_C,P_D}` that correspond to the *up to scale* 3d location of the points on the cube.

Since you know the width/height, you must have

```
scale_factor*(P_A-P_C)==height
scale_factor*(P_B-P_A)=width
```

So, this gives you a way to estimate the change of position/orientation of the object. But it probably wont be a robust solution and will only work in very simple situations.

If the object is not static, then its features will be outliers with respect to the Essential you have computed, so they wont be triangulated. The problem is considerably more difficult, but I suspect there might be a solution, for example based on optical flow, although I don't think two views will be enough.

I hope that this helps.